# AJAX: Getting ajax call javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

Is there any way to know (with some developers tools: chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc) what is last function that fires an AJAX call?

It would be interesting for debugging web apps.

Thank you

Comment: firebug or chrome developer tools are very powerful for debugging web apps, they basically have all features you could wish for

Comment: What does *"throws an AJAX call"* mean? Makes a call ? (only *errors* are thrown). By *"last function"* do you mean the function which most recently made an Ajax call at some point in time?

Comment: @x4rf41 The poster is asking how to do it, not can it do it.

Comment: I assume "throws" means "executes"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how I do it in Google Chrome:

1. Load your web app
2. Press F12 to open Chrome Developer Tools
3. Go to the **Profiles** tab
4. Select **Collect JavaScript CPU Profile**
5. Press **Start**
6. Use your web app as you normally would
7. When you're done using the web app, go back to Developer Tools and press **Stop**

As a result, you'll get a profile similar to the one shown in the picture below. This profile shows every JavaScript call made during the time you were capturing the profile, including any AJAX calls, as well as where in your code the call was made (which function "threw" the call).

[image]

As you can see in this other screenshot, I had an AJAX call fired from my script (dash.js, line 51), from a function called **doOnSelectDate()**, which was itself called from a function called getDailySummary() (defined on line 60).

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for!!!  Sorry for my English,  I just wanted to know what function executes an Ajax...  Better?

Comment: That's fine. We all knew what you meant. Your English is great. I'm glad you found what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Look at [`console.trace()`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#console-trace), it will give you the stack info you are after.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do this in Firefox and Chrome. For both I used W3Schools jQuery example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) so you can follow along exactly.

### For Firefox.

Trigger the event that calls the AJAX. Open up Firebug console and click the source link.

If you wrote your own low level AJAX function this will be enough and will take you to your source. But since most people will be using jQuery minimized you get the jquery.min.js link which is no help.

[image: Console with AJAX and link to source]

If you are using jquery.min.js, click on the link in the console and set a breakpoint at the line specified in the link (line 6).

[image: Placing the breakpoint]

Now trigger the AJAX again and it will stop at the breakpoint. Click on the stack tab and your call should be somewhere in there. Click on it and it will take you to the source.

[image: Finding source in stack trace]

### For Chrome

Open settings and enable "Log XMLHttpRequests"

[image: Log XMLHttpRequests setting]

Run your AJAX again and it will appear in the console. Expand it to see the stack trace.

[image: Finding the stack trace in the console]

Comment: how to see in chrome ?

Comment: Added instructions for Chrome

Answer (score -1):

you can use firebug in firefox. It allows you to have breakpoints in javascript code.

You can click on the script tab of firebug and select your script file and provide breakpoints at all AJAX calls and see which AJAX is being called last.

Answer (score -1):

Google chrome has developer tools:
    view -> developer -> developer tools

you are probably most interested in the network tab.

Firebug is also really good for debugging and the console there will show you the ajax requests. Firebug is a firefox addon.

Comment: network tab is not going to give the function that was called. It will show you that an Ajax call is made.